# Nuxt 3 Fails Production Build With vue-mail

Tags: javascript, vue.js, email, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a nuxt 3 application that is using vue-email module for nuxt to send emails using vue components templates. Everything works well in dev mode and emails are being send. However building for production fails with the error below:

```
 ERROR  Cannot resolve "canvas" from "C:\\Users\\Christian\\vscode\\clearbooks\\node_modules\\jsdom\\lib\\jsdom\\utils.js" and externals are not allowed!
```

I have tried installing canvas into my application but that only results in a new error below:

```
ERROR  node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node (1:2): Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
```

I am using the following versions of nuxt and vue-email/nuxt

```
"nuxt": "^3.11.1"
"@vue-email/nuxt": "^0.8.19"
```